# Why does jslint complains about my spaces?

Tags: javascript, jslint

This might not be a good question, but I'm gonna ask anyway...

so..I usually write a function like this

```
function name( param1, param2 )
{
}
```

somehow jslint complains about the space between ( and param1.

Is this really a problem?

Comment: It's just Crockford's convention for code readability. JS does not mind it actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, spaces are not significant in Javascript. However, most people write that code without a space after `(`, and jslint is just suggesting that you follow that same convention.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses that style, with spaces between parenthesis and parameters. It's just a matter of style and readability. In the end it all comes down to personal preference, I just turn off that "feature" in jslint, as well as many others.